# I am getting false testing result in counting table data

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, data-science, data-analysis

Hello guys hope you're doing well.

> I was trying to count data from a table in python, u can check the table below:
> [image: the table]

> I am trying to count number of data in a column of a table in the picture below: the column (table)

my main point is for example if: green on row 1 and row 2 then: green green ++ and if red is on row 1 and green on row 2 then : red green++ and if green is on row 1 and red on row 2 then : green red++ but in condition 2 and 3 I am getting the same results but it differs if green or red comes first in the table –
check the code down below:

```
finalData['Color']
greengreen = 0
greenred = 0
redgreen = 0
redred=0

for i in range(len(finalData)):
  if i < (len(finalData)-1): 
    if finalData['Color'][i] == 'green' and finalData['Color'][i+1] == 'green':
      greengreen += 1
    elif finalData['Color'][i] == 'green' and finalData['Color'][i+1] == 'red':
      greenred += 1
    elif finalData['Color'][i] == 'red' and finalData['Color'][i+1] == 'green':
      redgreen += 1
    elif finalData['Color'][i] == 'red' and finalData['Color'][i+1] == 'red':
      redred += 1
    else:
      print('?')

print("Value of greengreen bricks: ",greengreen)
print("Value of greenred bricks: ",greenred)
print("Value of redred bricks: ",redred)
print("Value of redgreen bricks: ",redgreen)
```

> The error I am facing is that the code is counting green after red(redgreen) and red after green(greenred) the same , meaning that I am get the same results for them and it is not supposed to happen,
> for example:
> the output
> Value of greengreen bricks:  1
> Value of greenred bricks:  2
> Value of redred bricks:  6
> Value of redgreen bricks:  2
> (green red and red green are always the same)

Comment: what is tour expected output?

Comment: Also post the data ad not images

Comment: In your dataset, indeed greenred is equal to redgreen by your definition . Why is it a problem ?

Comment: the number of red rows after the greens is different than the green rows after the red , they should not be the same , that is my point